# Convert the output of openssl command to JSON

Tags: python, json, openssl

The output of the `openssl` command looks like this:

```
serial=CABCSDUMMY4A168847703FGH
notAfter=Oct 21 16:43:47 2024 GMT
subject= /C=US/ST=WA/L=Seattle/O=MyCo/OU=TME/CN=MyCo.example.com
```

How do I convert this string to JSON?

I tried these:

```
temp_txt_bytes = subprocess.check_output (["openssl", "x509", "-serial", "-enddate", "-subject", "-noout", "-in", pem_file_name])

temp_txt_strings = temp_txt_bytes.decode("utf-8")

test = json.loads(temp_txt_strings) #json.parse, json.dump, and json.load also failing
```

Comment: Use `json.dumps` to convert _to_ JSON.

Comment: What do you want to serialize? A string of the output lines? That's just `json.dumps(temp_txt_strings)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split every line with "=" as a separator, put the two parts in an ordered dictionary and then dump it to json:

```
my_list = "serial=CABCSDUMMY4A168847703FGH".split("=")
ordered_dict = OrderedDict()
ordered_dict[my_list[0]] = my_list[1]
print(json.dumps(ordered_dict))
```

the output would be like this:

```
{"serial": "CABCSDUMMY4A168847703FGH"}
```

you can do it for all lines.
PS don't forget to import json and OrderedDict

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR use jc

```bash
cat certificate.crt | jc --x509-cert    # json
cat certificate.crt | jc --x509-cert -y # yaml
```

---

Details

- tool: [github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jc](https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jc?tab=readme-ov-file#os-package-repositories)
- examples: [Convert X.509 Certificates to JSON with JC](https://blog.kellybrazil.com/2022/07/14/convert-x-509-certificates-to-json-with-jc/)
- more examples: [Bringing the Unix Philosophy to the 21st Century](https://blog.kellybrazil.com/2019/11/26/bringing-the-unix-philosophy-to-the-21st-century/)